# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Оглянись на огни уходящие вдаль.

Answer (score 1):

**Оглянись на огни, уходящие вдаль.**

Запятая нужна, потому что *уходящие вдаль* — причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

Comment: Добавьте еще "стоящий после определяемого слова", и будет идеально.  Это основа ответа (необходимая информация).  Второй уровень — ссылки, пояснения, примеры. Почему так? Мы (отвечающие) про причастный оборот знаем практически всё, а вот для автор вопроса  главная информация должна быть четкой, краткой,  доступной  (дальше он, может, и читать не будет).

Comment: Кстати, комментарий связан с вашим "стилем", на который вам недавно было указано (если я, конечно, всё правильно поняла). Поэтому тема моего комментария – о СТИЛЯХ ответов вообще. Ведь в принципе тему можно рассмотреть ещЕ глубже –  есть случаи, когда определение в этой позиции не обособляется.  Но очевидно, что такая подробная информация здесь не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

*Уходящий* — это причастие.
*Уходящий* (куда?) *вдаль* — это причастный оборот (причастие + зависимое слово).
На огни (какие?), уходящие вдаль — причастный оборот находится **после** определяемого слова, поэтому перед ним [оборотом] ставится запятая.
*Оглянись на огни, уходящие вдаль.*

Мигнули два раза и зажглись вдоль всего бульвара над берегом реки **фонари, уходящие вдаль редкой цепочкой**. [Федор Кнорре. Шорох сухих листьев (1967)]

Сравните (без запятой, когда причастный оборот стоит **перед** определяемым словом):
Свет фонаря выхватывал из темноты **уходящие вдаль стены** подземной галереи. [Наталья Александрова. Последний ученик да Винчи (2010)]

[Согласованные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)